# Oracle Database exists but error seen when referencing it

Tags: linux, database, oracle

During installation of spacewalk using instructions from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E92593_01/E90682/html/swk22-svr-install.html we require

We require to use a database. So using dbca i created an Oracle database called orcl.ie.oracle.com

However this seems to either not see it or not connect. Not sure why - see below.

```
spacewalk-setup --external-oracle
* Setting up Oracle environment.
* Setting up database.
** Database: Setting up database connection for Oracle backend.
Global Database Name or SID (requires tnsnames.ora)? orcl.ie.oracle.com
Database hostname [localhost]?
Database (listener) port [1521]?
*** Database connection error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)
Global Database Name or SID (requires tnsnames.ora)?
```

From feedback, here is output of lsnctl stat

```
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# pwd
/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# echo $PATH

[oracle@dub-mgrfarm113 oracle]$ ./product/19c/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 14-NOV-2019 11:16:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1053 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12541: Message 12541 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00511: Message 511 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

can you post what the following command gives on your server:
lsnrctl stat

(started connected as the user who owns the oracle installation, and after initializing your env to use the database installation, i.e. correct ORACLE_HOME and PATH)

UPDATE (Using this as I cannot yet comment on posts):
You show the ORACLE_HOME var from root, then you execute lsnrctl as 'oracle'. The fact that you had to use the full path to start lsnrctl indicates that your env is not properly set).
Please connect as 'oracle', then do (and enter the db name when asked for):

```
. oraenv
```

then run the lsnrctl command

Comment: [root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# pwd
/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1//bin
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 dbhome_1]# ./bin/lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 14-NOV-2019 09:32:26

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01150: The address of the specifie